# Looping over an object within React render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some JSON that I am looping over in my React app. Within the JSON I am looping over I have an object which contains multiple images. I would like to loop through these images and render each of them as well. Here is what I tried:

```js
const locations = [
  {
    "name": "First Location",
    "photos": [
      {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }, {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Second Location",
    "photos": [
      {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }, {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }
    ]
  }
]

const element = (
  <div className="community-list">
    {locations && locations.map((location, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="location">
        <h2>{location.name}</h2>
        {Object.keys(location.photos).map(function(key) {
          return <img src="{location.photos[url]}" />;
        })}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('mountNode'));
```

However this gives me 2 broken images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem, There is an extra double quotes for img tag.
Remove the double quotes enclosing the curly braces. Your images will be displayed

```
<img src={location.photos[url]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do is this:

```
const locations = [
  {
    "name": "First Location",
    "photos": [
      {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }, {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Second Location",
    "photos": [
      {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }, {
        "url": "http://placehold.it/250x250",
      }
    ]
  }
]

const element = (
  <div className="community-list">
    {locations && locations.map((location, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="location">
        <h2>{location.name}</h2>
        {location.photos.map(function(photo) {
          return <img src="{photo.url}" />;
        })}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('mountNode'));
```

What this would do is iterate through the `photos` array of a `location`, and then use the `url` node of the `photo` object.

Comment: Thank you for the response, between your answer and Gangadhar's answer above I was able to get it working! Turns out you don't need to enclose the url in quotation marks.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's one way of doing it too. Alright man, good luck on your app!